# What do these numbers tell me when comparing two lines with diff?

Tags: diff

Maybe I just don't see the wood for the trees. I am trying to understand how to interpret the highlighted numbers.

This is taken from the manual page.

```
diff -u lao tzu
```

The difference is given as:

```
--- lao Sat Jan 26 23:30:39 1991
+++ tzu Sat Jan 26 23:30:50 1991
```

`@@`**`-1,7 +1,6`**`@@`

```
-The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
-The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
 The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
-The Named is the mother of all things.
+The named is the mother of all things.
+
 Therefore let there always be non-being,
   so we may see their subtlety,
 And let there always be being,
```

`@@`**`-9,3 +8,6`**`@@`

```
 The two are the same,
 But after they are produced,
   they have different names.
+They both may be called deep and profound.
+Deeper and more profound,
+The door of all subtleties!
```

The help file says:

```
@@ from-file-range to-file-range @@
 line-from-either-file
 line-from-either-file...
```

How do I have to interpret `@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@` and `@@ -9,3 +8,6 @@`? Probably, this is really obvious, but I just don't get the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `@@-1,7 +1,6@@`

That tells you what lines of the files the following change hunk apply to.

- -1 means that the following change hunk starts on line 1 of the original file.
- 7 means that the change hunk applies to 7 lines of the original file.
- +1 means that the change hunk starts on line 1 of the new file.
- 6 means that the change hunk applies to 6 lines of the new file.

In the change hunk that follows, lines preceded with a `-` were deletion lines, lines preceded with a `+` were addition lines, and lines preceded with a  (space) were unchanged.

Reference: [diff - Unified format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format)